# Combine two MySQL tables, use data in one for headers in the combined table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, pivot-table

I want to combine two MySQL tables, but use some data in one of them as new headers in the combined one. I have two tables, like this:

A log of fruits we've eaten each day.

```
id date       fruit
5  2011-11-27 banana
4  2011-11-26 apple
3  2011-11-25 orange
2  2011-11-24 banana
1  2011-11-23 pear
```

A table with what we think of the fruits we've eaten.

```
id user   fruit  rating
7  andrew banana yum
6  andrew apple  eww
5  lisa   apple  yum
4  andrew orange yum
3  lisa   orange yum
2  andrew pear   eww
1  lisa   pear   eww
```

What I'm looking for is a SQL query with a result something like this:

```
date       fruit  andrew lisa
2011-11-27 banana yum    NULL
2011-11-26 apple  eww    yum
2011-11-25 orange yum    yum
2011-11-24 banana yum    NULL
2011-11-23 pear   eww    eww
```

I suppose I'm not the first to want something like this; but it is not very easy to look for the answer when you have no idea to describe it except by showing the tables and the desired result.

---

For my own experimenting, I have now actually created the example tables I use above. (What I really need it for is conceptually similar, but I don't actually know anyone named andrew and I don't log fruits we eat. Anyhow, the real tables are somewhat larger and more complicated - these will do for describing the concept.

```sql
--
-- Table structure `fruit_log`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `fruit_log` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `fruit` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;

--
-- Dumping of data in table `fruit_log`
--

INSERT INTO `fruit_log` (`id`, `date`, `fruit`) VALUES
(1, '2011-11-23', 'pear'),
(2, '2011-11-24', 'banana'),
(3, '2011-11-25', 'orange'),
(4, '2011-11-26', 'apple'),
(5, '2011-11-27', 'banana');

--
-- Table structure `fruit_log`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `fruit_ratings` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `user` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
  `fruit` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
  `rating` enum('yum','eww') default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;

--
-- Dumping of data in table `fruit_ratings`
--

INSERT INTO `fruit_ratings` (`id`, `user`, `fruit`, `rating`) VALUES
(1, 'lisa', 'pear', 'eww'),
(2, 'andrew', 'pear', 'eww'),
(3, 'lisa', 'orange', 'yum'),
(4, 'andrew', 'orange', 'yum'),
(5, 'lisa', 'apple', 'yum'),
(6, 'andrew', 'apple', 'eww'),
(7, 'andrew', 'banana', 'yum');
```

---

I've learnt a lot trying to find an answer to this question. To begin with, "pivot tables" as a concept, introduced to me by @w0051977 . w0051977's link is however specific to Microsoft SQL Server - I run MySQL. I was introduced to the concept, anyway, and looked further. I learnt some things from Wikipedia and a lot from this chronicle: http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/wizard/print_version.html

However; I have been unable to find anything that even remotely resembles my goal. The hard part seems to be using a dynamic number of cell data (data from the "user" column: "andrew" and "lisa" in my example, but could also include "bob" and perhaps even "alice", etc) and "flipping" them over to instead act as column headers.

The Wizard does this in the chronicle linked above, but not in a single query: he uses a clever SQL trick to generate part of another SQL query that can be pasted into the query that does what he wanted to do to begin with. Of course you don't have to actually copy and paste it - the Wizard automates it with Perl, and I'd do it with PHP (this is part of a PHP-based project). But if I have to use PHP to generate a query anyway, I might as well do it a simpler way.

@adam-wenger suggested that I use LEFT JOIN, but noted that it would only use for a limited number of users. This is his query, adapted to the table names I introduced above in an edit after his answer was posted.

```
SELECT fruit_log.date, fruit_log.fruit, a.rating AS 'andrew', l.rating AS 'lisa'
FROM fruit_log
LEFT JOIN fruit_ratings AS a
    ON fruit_log.fruit = a.fruit
    AND a.user = 'andrew'
LEFT JOIN fruit_ratings AS l
    ON fruit_log.fruit = l.fruit
    AND l.user = 'lisa'
ORDER BY date DESC
```

With PHP, I can generate as many LEFT JOINs as I need, thus solving my problem. I can also use sub-queries, as thus:

```
SELECT fruit_log.date, fruit_log.fruit, (
    SELECT fruit_ratings.rating
    FROM fruit_ratings
    WHERE fruit_ratings.user = 'andrew'
    AND fruit_ratings.fruit = fruit_log.fruit
) AS 'andrew', (
    SELECT fruit_ratings.rating
    FROM fruit_ratings
    WHERE fruit_ratings.user = 'lisa'
    AND fruit_ratings.fruit = fruit_log.fruit
) AS 'lisa'
FROM fruit_log
ORDER BY date DESC
```

I suppose one of them is more efficient than the other, but I don't know which one (if I have the time and the interest I'll do a benchmark some time, unless someone provides insight before that happens).

If someone has a one query solution to my problem, it would be very appreciated. Until then; I'll have to stick to PHP ducttape (and this question will remain unanswered).

Answer (score 2):

If you only have two users, `andrew` and `lisa`, you can approach the problem with `LEFT JOIN`: (you'll have to update table names, as they were not in the question, I guessed)

```
SELECT fl.Date, fl.fruit, a.rating AS 'Andrew', l.rating AS 'Lisa'
FROM fruitLog AS fl
LEFT JOIN thoughts AS a ON fl.fruit = a.fruit
   AND a.user = 'andrew'
LEFT JOIN thoughts AS l ON fl.fruit = l.fruit
   AND l.user = 'lisa'
ORDER BY fl.Date DESC
```

If you had additional users, more could be added with Additional `LEFT JOINS`

Comment: Unfortunately, I have an unknown number of users - of course I could add new joins when generating the SQL query in the PHP code, though.

Comment: @jobjorn It looks like you will have to do some type of `Pivot` then if you have an unknown number of users.  MySQL does not provide great out of the box `Pivot` support, but there are many sites that show you how to replicate the functionality.

Comment: I have been unable to find anything like what I'm looking for - you can see my description of the quest above, in the question text. Thank you for your help, anyhow!

Answer (score 1):

I think you will have to use an SQL Pivot.  Have a look at a tutorial: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2009/03/03/pivot-tables-in-sql-server-a-simple-sample.aspx.

Comment: This looks promising. I'll report back when I've had time to try it out!

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't help, though I've learnt a lot. I've described my quest in the question above.

Comment: The link is broken now.

Answer (score 0):

A pivot table is probably what you're looking for, as suggested by w0051977 and Adam. Here's some info on creating pivot queries in MySQL: http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#78. You'd probably be interested in the second topic "automate pivot table queries". Not an easy query to get running though...